# System Uptime & MemoryBarrier

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory-barriers

I need a robust way of getting system uptime, and ended up using something as follows.
Added some comments to help people read it.  I cannot use Task's as this has to run on a .NET 3.5 application.

```
// This is a structure, can't be marked as volatile
// need to implement MemoryBarrier manually as appropriate
private static TimeSpan _uptime;

private static TimeSpan GetUptime()
{
    // Try and set the Uptime using per counters
    var uptimeThread = new Thread(GetPerformanceCounterUptime);
    uptimeThread.Start();

    // If our thread hasn't finished in 5 seconds, perf counters are broken
    if (!uptimeThread.Join(5 * 1000))
    {
        // Kill the thread and use Environment.TickCount
        uptimeThread.Abort();
        _uptime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(
            Environment.TickCount & Int32.MaxValue);
    }

    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    return _uptime;
}

// This sets the System uptime using the perf counters
// this gives the best result but on a system with corrupt perf counters
// it can freeze
private static void GetPerformanceCounterUptime()
{
    using (var uptime = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time"))
    {
        uptime.NextValue();
        _uptime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(uptime.NextValue());
    }
}
```

The part I am struggling with is where should `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` be placed?
I am placing it before reading the value, but either the current thread or a different thread could have written to it.  Does the above look correct?

**Edit, Answer based on Daniel**

This is what I eneded up implementing, thank you both for the insight.

```
private static TimeSpan _uptime;

private static TimeSpan GetUptime()
{
    var uptimeThread = new Thread(GetPerformanceCounterUptime);
    uptimeThread.Start();

    if (uptimeThread.Join(5*1000))
    {
        return _uptime;
    }
    else
    {
        uptimeThread.Abort();
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(
            Environment.TickCount & Int32.MaxValue);
    }
}

private static void GetPerformanceCounterUptime()
{
    using (var uptime = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time"))
    {
        uptime.NextValue();
        _uptime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(uptime.NextValue());
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

Updated based on Bob's comments.

```
private static DateTimeOffset _uptime;

private static DateTimeOffset GetUptime()
{
    var uptimeThread = new Thread(GetPerformanceCounterUptime);
    uptimeThread.Start();

    if (uptimeThread.Join(5*1000))
    {
        return _uptime;
    }
    else
    {
        uptimeThread.Abort();
        return DateTimeOffset.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(
            Environment.TickCount & Int32.MaxValue));
    }
}

private static void GetPerformanceCounterUptime()
{
    if (_uptime != default(DateTimeOffset))
    {
        return;
    }

    using (var uptime = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time"))
    {
        uptime.NextValue();
        _uptime = DateTimeOffset.Now.Subtract(
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(uptime.NextValue()));
    }
}
```

Comment: are you saying that the perf counter can get corrupt during the life time of the application? this is why you start new thread each time to check?

Comment: @Bobb, mmm not sure.  My application is a windows service that starts on machine start up.  I have seen it corrupt, and my application always runs.  Its likely that it will happen during the lifetime of the application on some machines.  PS, I appreciate that I can do some caching, add DateTime.Now as a member variable, and if they are both not null compute the new uptime value.  Will probably change the code to do that to ensure I don't spawn off potentially loads of "unabortable" threads.

Comment: Creating and starting a thread just to get a timer value is so wrong that I dont even know where to start. you should take the snapshot of uptime once at the start somehow (I cant comment on your 'corruption' notion) and the local time using hi-res clock (plenty of examples on google). and on each GetUpTime you simply return initialUpTime + (timeNow - timeAtUpTimeSnapshot). this call will take few lines of code, will be synchronous, predictable and manageable... what you are doing now doesnt make any sense at all.

Comment: @Bobb I agree that starting a thread _every_ time is just lazy.  Updated as appropriate.  But I do need a separate thread for the first run.  Although admitedly, uptime is misleading, more like last boot time.

Comment: thats it. just lock uptime taking (2 lines of code inside using). you dont need memory barrier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.Join` already ensures that writes performed by the uptimeThread are visible on the main thread. You don't need any explicit memory barrier. (without the synchronization performed by `Join`, you'd need barriers on both threads - after the write and before the read)

However, there's a potential problem with your code: writing to a `TimeSpan` struct isn't atomic, and the main thread and the uptimeThread may write to it at the same time (`Thread.Abort` just signals abortion, but doesn't wait for the thread to finish aborting), causing a torn write.
My solution would be to not use the field at all when aborting. Also, multiple concurrent calls to `GetUptime()` may cause the same problem, so you should use an instance field instead.

```
private static TimeSpan GetUptime()
{
    // Try and set the Uptime using per counters
    var helper = new Helper();
    var uptimeThread = new Thread(helper.GetPerformanceCounterUptime);
    uptimeThread.Start();

    // If our thread hasn't finished in 5 seconds, perf counters are broken
    if (uptimeThread.Join(5 * 1000))
    {
        return helper._uptime;
    } else {
        // Kill the thread and use Environment.TickCount
        uptimeThread.Abort();
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(
            Environment.TickCount & Int32.MaxValue);
    }
}

class Helper
{
    internal TimeSpan _uptime;

    // This sets the System uptime using the perf counters
    // this gives the best result but on a system with corrupt perf counters
    // it can freeze
    internal void GetPerformanceCounterUptime()
    {
        using (var uptime = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time"))
        {
            uptime.NextValue();
            _uptime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(uptime.NextValue());
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure if aborting the performance counter thread will work correctly at all - `Thread.Abort()` only aborts managed code execution. If the code is hanging within a Windows API call, the thread will keep running.

Comment: could you clarify why Thread.Join() would guarantee the writes completed on one processor is seen by the reads of another?  Agreed about the problem being the field, I would have implemented as a Task<TimeSpan> if it weren't for the .NET 3.5 requirement.

Comment: @M Afifi: `Thread.Join` carries an implicit memory barrier when called.

Comment: Generally, operations that wait for an action (e.g. thread exit) to happen on another thread, also ensure that all memory writes that happened prior to the action are visible after the wait completes. "Wait until X is done" would be pretty useless if it didn't imply "Wait until I can see that results of X".
Unfortunately the Microsoft .NET API documentation doesn't mention memory order effects explicitly. (the Java documentation is much better in this regard)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK writes in .NET are volatile, so the only place where you would need a memory fence would be before each read, since they are subject to reordering and/or caching. To quote from [a post by Joe Duffy](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2007/11/10/CLR20MemoryModel.aspx):

> For reference, here are the rules as I have come to understand them
>   stated as simply as I can:
>
> ```
> Rule 1: Data dependence among loads and stores is never violated.
> Rule 2: All stores have release semantics, i.e. no load or store may move after one.
> Rule 3: All volatile loads are acquire, i.e. no load or store may move before one.
> Rule 4: No loads and stores may ever cross a full-barrier. 
> Rule 5: Loads and stores to the heap may never be introduced.
> Rule 6: Loads and stores may only be deleted when coalescing adjacent loads and 
> stores from/to the same location.
> ```
>
> Note that by this definition, non-volatile loads are not required to
>   have any sort of barrier associated with them.  So loads may be freely
>   reordered, and writes may move after them (though not before, due to
>   Rule 2).  With this model, the only true case where you’d truly need
>   the strength of a full-barrier provided by Rule 4 is to prevent
>   reordering in the case where a store is followed by a volatile load. 
>   Without the barrier, the instructions may reorder.

Comment: The store being implicitly volatile on the .NET CLR implementation (the rules you posted are not guaranteed by the specification!) doesn't help here, as the store isn't atomic.

Comment: @Daniel: Since the OP was discussing volatile/memory fences I was under the impression that he's only asking about visibility, not atomicity.

Comment: The question being asked was "is this code correct?", and visibility without atomicity is useless there.